# Change Storybook v7 Documentation Theme at runtime

Tags: vue.js, storybook

Is there a way to change the theme of the Documentation at runtime? I managed to do it for both the Storybook instance and the Story itself, but the autogenerated doc seems not to be affected.

```
import type { Preview } from '@storybook/vue3';
import { themes } from '@storybook/theming';
import { FORCE_RE_RENDER } from '@storybook/core-events';


import { addons } from '@storybook/preview-api';

import '../src/theme/index.scss'
import '../src/theme/themes.scss'
function addClass(theme :string = 'light') {
  var element = document.getElementsByTagName("html");
  element[0].classList.add(theme);
}

localStorage.setItem('theme', JSON.stringify(themes.light))
addClass()
const preview: Preview = {
  parameters: {
    layout: 'centered',

    actions: { argTypesRegex: '^on[A-Z].*' },
    docs: {
      theme:JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('theme')) // The replacement theme to use

    },
    controls: {
      matchers: {
        color: /(background|color)$/i,
        date: /Date$/,
      },
    },
  },
};


setTimeout(() => {
  addClass('dark')
  localStorage.setItem('theme', JSON.stringify(themes.dark))
  addons.getChannel().emit(FORCE_RE_RENDER);
}, 4000)



export default preview;
```

i did try a lot of things this is my current implementation that also doesnt work. And the docs does not seem to give a proper solution here.

Also same thing works in the manager.ts

```
import { addons } from '@storybook/manager-api';
import { themes } from '@storybook/theming';

addons.setConfig({
  theme: themes.light,
});

setTimeout(() => {
  addons.setConfig({
    theme: themes.dark,
  });
  
  console.log('theme changed')
}, 4000)
```

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be a need to do this with timeouts.

Here's an example using React & MUI Themes, but I expect you should be able to use something quite similar to this. The key being that you implement a decorator for rendering your stories. Switching the theme happens through the globalType `theme` that can then be chosen in the story toolbar.

```js
import { createTheme, CssBaseline, styled, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material';
import { themes } from './themes';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const ThemingDecorator = (Story, context) => {
  const {theme: themeName} = context.globals;

  const selectedTheme = themes.find(theme => theme.themeName === themeName);
  const createdTheme = selectedTheme ? createTheme(selectedTheme) : createTheme();

  useEffect(() => {
    document.body.style.background = selectedTheme.palette.background.default;
  }, [themeName]);

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={createdTheme}>
      <CssBaseline/>
      <Story/>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};


const preview = {
  parameters: {
    actions: {argTypesRegex: '^on[A-Z].*'},
    controls: {
      matchers: {
        color: /(background|color)$/i,
        date: /Date$/,
      },
    },
  },
  globalTypes: {
    theme: {
      title: 'Theme',
      description: 'MUI Theme',
      defaultValue: themes[0].themeName,
      toolbar: {
        icon: 'paintbrush',
        items: themes.map(theme => ({value: theme.themeName, title: theme.themeName})),
        dynamicTitle: true,
      },
    },
  },
  decorators: [
    ThemingDecorator
  ]
};

export default preview;
```

Hope this helps :)